# Linq for calculating rank with group and orderby

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to calculate the rank of objects. Since multiple objects can have the same score I would need to group them so they get the same rank.

```
public class RankedItem {

  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Score {get; set; }
  public int Rank {get; set; }

  public RankedItem(string name, int score) {
     Name = name;
     Score = score;
  }

}

public void CalculateRanks() {

  List<RankedItem> items = new List<RankedItems> {
    new RankedItem("A", 3),
    new RankedItem("B", 2),
    new RankedItem("C", 3),
    new RankedItem("D", 1),
    new RankedItem("E", 2)
  };
 
  IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<int, RankedItems>> rankedItems = items.GroupBy(i => b.Score).OrderBy(g => g.Key);

  
}
```

How can I set the rank now, so that rank `1` will be assigned to the highest score?

Comment: set the rank according to the grouping "key". How gets the highest rank? the one with the highest score? or the lowest? Please give an expected output. I don't know how you scale the ranks and how the relationship score to rank is supposed to be

Comment: rank 1 is the highest score

Comment: "rank 1 is the highest score" then you need to ordery them descending :`OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy` and then take the index of the grouping +1 for the rank

Comment: Set rank to one, order by score descending, then go trough each group and give every item in the group that rank, then increment the rank before you go to the next group?

Comment: in which collection do you want your result to be? in a list?

Comment: actually I try to update RankedItem.Rank

Comment: "actually I try to update RankedItem.Rank" I understand that. But you cannot apply the `[ ]` operator on an `IOrderedEnumerable` collection. So you cannot use a loop here. You could filter and make a proper select right after the grouping. Would you be happy if you get your restults in a `List<RankedItem> rankedItems ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically 2 options here. Linq or Loop. For both options you should use `OrderByDescending` since your score rank relationship is inverse. Then you can use the index + 1 to assign the ranks.

1. Loop.

for this option you need a collection to hold your groupings which can be iterated using the index `[ ]` operator. This is not possible in `IOrderedEnumerable`. So I suggest to use a `List`:

```
List<IGrouping<int, RankedItem>> rankedItems = items.GroupBy(b => b.Score)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                                                    .ToList();
```

Now you can simply loop through the list having the index and loop again through all elements of each group to use the index to assign the rank:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rankedItems.Count(); i++)
{
    IGrouping<int, RankedItem> grouping = rankedItems[i];
    foreach (var element in grouping)
    {
        element.Rank = i + 1;
    }
}
```

2. LINQ:

Use the index in this [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload statement and create new objects using your constructor:

```
List<RankedItem> rankedItems = items.GroupBy(b => b.Score)
                                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                                    .SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(inner => 
                                            new RankedItem(inner.Name, item.Key) {Rank = index + 1})
                                    ).ToList();
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: works for the example given though I get some weird impossible values in my real life application. But I guess they are due to my further modifications.

Comment: @monty impossible values for the ranks? what modification did you do?

Comment: added another orderby at the end (to sort by name) and converted it to an array.  With a list of 12 items I get ranks with 24+ :-)

Comment: @monty ok that's impossible for sure. If you post the orderby name code, may be we can fix this also

Comment: algorithm works, just used to wrong array for the logs

Comment: @monty ok, nice to hear that we solved your problem! happy coding mate